# Edimax Wireless Adapter conflict with Logitech Unifying Receiver

Tags: wireless-networking, mouse, peripherals

first post on a Stack Exch community here.

I just recently finished a PC build for my mother. Because she "hate[s] wires," I went with the [Edimax EW-7811Un](http://us.edimax.com/edimax/merchandise/merchandise_detail/data/edimax/us/wireless_adapters_n150/ew-7811un/) wireless adapter and the [Dell KM714](http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=dhs&cs=19&sku=332-1396) wireless keyboard/mouse.

The computer is running Win 8.1 Pro, and the appropriate driver for the adapter has been installed. The problem is this-- *the periphery receiver prevents the Wi-Fi adapter from working*.

I am confident in saying this because, when building my own computer with the same adapter some time ago, I had to substitute a wired mouse for the Logitech Unifying Receiver which I had been using prior. Only then could my computer be given an IP address. N.B. the Dell receiver is an implementation of Logitech technology.

As it is, the computer recognizes only one of the several networks which reach into the room. When I connect to it, in informs me that the connection is limited. I cannot ping, tracert, or use the Web.

I'd like to know if I can change either receiver so that one does not interfere with the other.

Thank you.

Comment: The wireless keyboard/mouse uses a USB dongle? If so try them in different USB ports. My logitech mouse dongle will not work (without stuttering etc) if is plugged into a port adjacent to a USB 3 4-way hub, but it works fine plugged in to the opposite side of my laptop...

Comment: @DavidPostill , Both are plugged into separate USB 2.0 blocks in the back I/O. The periphery receiver is in the same block as the PS/2 port. The Wi-Fi adapter is in the same block as the RJ45 port.

Comment: Do you have a front port you could try?

Comment: @DavidPostill , These are the only two USB devices connected to the computer. In any case, where I put the devices does not affect the performance.

Comment: Oh well, it was just a suggestion based on my strange experience.